# Python Selenium switch into an iframe within an iframe

Tags: python, iframe, selenium

I am trying to access an iframe within an iframe using Selenium, Python, and BS4

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import html5lib

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(10)

driver.get('http://myurl.com')
try:
    time.sleep(4)
    iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0]
    driver.switch_to_default_content()

    driver.switch_to_frame(iframe)
    driver.switch_to_default_content()
    driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0]

    output = driver.page_source

    print output

finally:
    driver.quit();
```

Within the returned text, there appears to be two more iframes. How would I access those? I have attempted in the code above without success.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`switch_to_default_content()` will return you to the top of the document.  What was happening is you switched into the first `iframe`, switched back to the top of the document, then tried to find the second `iframe`.  Selenium can't find the second `iframe`, because it's inside of the first `iframe`.

If you remove the second `switch_to_default_content()` you should be fine:

```
iframe = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0]
driver.switch_to.default_content()

driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('iframe')[0]
```