# How to switch to the Facebook messages frame using SeleniumWebdriver?

Tags: python, facebook, selenium, selenium-webdriver, chrome-web-driver

I'm trying to count my Facebook messages with friends, using Selenium Webdriver.

The messenger window has a frame containing the messages, but it must be scrolled to the start of the message history for all of the messages to be counted. My issue is with selecting that frame.

Upon inspecting the element, it notes that it is a `<div>` with an `id` of `"js_1"`, which is not a frame tag (`<iframe>`). Thus `driver_switch_to.frame()` is not a direct option.

Another suggestion was to `driver_switch_to.frame(driver.find_element_by_id("js_1"))`, or something of the like, but this also did not work.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23302769/python-selenium-switch-into-an-iframe-within-an-iframe ,  Refer this link.

Comment: on messenger.com or facebook.com/messages?

Comment: facebook.com/messages

Comment: The first comment doesn't help because it doesn't have an iframe tag