# Not rendering entire page with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I need the entire web page source for scraping, but I'm getting only a part of it.

Code trials:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
driver.get(url)

time.sleep(10)

page = driver.page_source
driver.quit()
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html5lib')

return soup
```

The website is: https://superbet.ro/pariuri-sportive/fotbal/live

Answer (score 0):

the may issue occurs because of the presence of <iframe> you would need to switch between iframes in order to get the corresponding data.

This might help: [Switching into second iframe in Selenium Python3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54890250/switching-into-second-iframe-in-selenium-python3)

Comment: Now, when I'm scrolling down with the page source opened, some events and code are added while scrolling. That's because of iframe existence?

Comment: No that would be the client side Javascript(Ajax)

Answer (score 0):

To extract the page source you need to:

- Click on <kbd>OK</kbd> button to accept the cookies.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the visibility of an [WebElement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52782684/what-is-the-difference-between-webdriver-and-webelement-in-selenium/52805139#52805139) using [`visibility_of_element_located()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59644133/how-to-print-a-message-when-error-message-is-displayed-on-website-selenium/59646825#59646825).
- You can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

  - Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://superbet.ro/pariuri-sportive/fotbal/live")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a#CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonAccept[href]"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.section-header__title")))
    ```
  - Using `XPATH`:

    ```
    driver.get("https://superbet.ro/pariuri-sportive/fotbal/live")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//a[@id='CybotCookiebotDialogBodyLevelButtonAccept' and @href]"))).click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='section-header__title']")))
    ```
- Console Output:

```html
<html lang="en" style="--vh:6.13px;">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=0">
  <title>Superbet | Pariuri Sportive Online, Live, Casino, Loto, Virtuale</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" async="" src="https://consentcdn.cookiebot.com/consentconfig/a438e411-35ff-432b-863f-3d25bed37901/state.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" async="" src="https://consent.cookiebot.com/logconsent.ashx?action=accept&amp;nocache=1612037844156&amp;referer=https%3A%2F%2Fsuperbet.ro%2Fpariuri-sportive%2Ffotbal%2Flive&amp;dnt=false&amp;method=strict&amp;clp=true&amp;cls=true&amp;clm=true&amp;cbid=a438e411-35ff-432b-863f-3d25bed37901&amp;cbt=leveloptin&amp;hasdata=true"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8" async="" src="https://consent.cookiebot.com/a438e411-35ff-432b-863f-3d25bed37901/cc.js?renew=false&amp;referer=superbet.ro&amp;dnt=false&amp;forceshow=false&amp;cbid=a438e411-35ff-432b-863f-3d25bed37901&amp;whitelabel=false&amp;brandid=CookieConsent&amp;framework="></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="https://consent.cookiebot.com/uc.js?cbid=a438e411-35ff-432b-863f-3d25bed37901"></script>
  <script async="" src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-MN5RWMH"></script>
  <script>
    if (!window.location.hostname.includes('local')) {
      window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
      window.dataLayer.push({
        originalLocation: document.location.protocol + '//' +
          document.location.hostname +
          document.location.pathname +
          document.location.search
      });
      (function(w, d, s, l, i) {
        w[l] = w[l] || [];
        w[l].push({
          'gtm.start': new Date().getTime(),
          event: 'gtm.js'
        });
        var f = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
          j = d.createElement(s),
          dl = l != 'dataLayer' ? '&l=' + l : '';
        j.async = true;
        j.src = 'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=' + i + dl;
        f.parentNode.insertBefore(j, f);
      })(window, document, 'script', 'dataLayer', 'GTM-MN5RWMH');
    }
  </script>
  . 
  . 
  .
  <iframe data-product="web_widget" title="No content" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" src="about:blank" style="width: 0px; height: 0px; border: 0px; position: absolute; top: -9999px;"></iframe><iframe name="__uspapiLocator" tabindex="-1" role="presentation"
    aria-hidden="true" title="Blank" style="display: none; position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px; top: -9999px;"></iframe><iframe tabindex="-1" role="presentation" aria-hidden="true" title="Blank" src="https://consentcdn.cookiebot.com/sdk/bc-v2.min.html"
    style="position: absolute; width: 1px; height: 1px; top: -9999px;"></iframe>
  <div><iframe title="Deschide o miniaplicație widget unde puteți găsi mai multe informații" id="launcher" tabindex="-1" style="width: 142px; height: 50px; padding: 0px; margin: 10px 20px; position: fixed; bottom: 30px; overflow: visible; opacity: 0; border: 0px; z-index: 999998; transition-duration: 250ms; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1); transition-property: opacity, top, bottom; top: -9999px; visibility: hidden;"></iframe>
    <iframe
      title="Găsiți mai multe informații aici" id="webWidget" tabindex="-1" style="width: 374px; max-height: calc(100vh - 32px); height: 572px; position: fixed; opacity: 0; border: 0px; transition-duration: 250ms; transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1); transition-property: opacity, top, bottom; top: -9999px; visibility: hidden; z-index: 999999;"></iframe>
  </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [How to retrieve html source from the web application WindGuru](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52993001/how-to-retrieve-page-source-from-the-web-application-windguru/53006894#53006894)
- [Scraping content from a dynamic webpage with Selenium returns wrong content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62740312/scraping-content-from-a-dynamic-webpage-with-selenium-returns-wrong-content/62740590#62740590)
- [crawl javascript table but considered abnormal requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58833294/crawl-javascript-table-but-considered-abnormal-requests/58835310#58835310)